# How can we rescue a survivor trapped in the desert?

Tags: die2nite

One of our town is stuck in the desert, one km south of town at [0,-1].

He has eaten, he has drunk, he is hung over and has used a drug. He also has lost an eye (auwch.) We have no coffee, no dice and no cards.

How can we save him? I think we have one anebolic steroids in the bank, can he use 2 drugs in a day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- If your friend has hero status, he can use Heroic return if he hasn't yet in this town.
- If somebody in your town has hero status, he can use Rescue if he hasn't yet in this town.
- If he finds more drugs, he can use them indeed. He'll become [addicted](http://www.die2nite.com/#help?sk=b0bc2), but that's (arguably) better than dead.

Comment: I have survived several days with hooked status, it was actually a benefit to the town, i scavanged more than anyone could, since i was already addicted, i could walk all i wanted as long as i took drugs and watched the dehydration status. I cleared a entire sector of zombies, scavanged like crazy, brought in lots of blueprints, saved people that were stuck, and many other things like "hyper building" (imagine using rested AP+water+food+alcohol+ 4 or 5 twinoids... once i managed to use more than 60 AP into a building). Of course you need alot of drugs for this, wich are something rare. In the

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should all just accept this as natural selection at work? ;)

[Joking aside, you need to consider the implications of rescuing a junkie [effectively]. If he uses drug s to get back, he'll be hooked - and he'll start hoovering up all the drugs in your bank, just to stay alive one more day - drugs that might be far better used elsewhere. Just food for thought...]

Comment: lol. unfortunatly, he is one of the few active members that has a possitive attitude. i doubt we will live to see much more then tommorow. if we are lucky. well, i suppose he will die2nite.

Comment: Joking aside, you need to consider the implications of rescuing a junkie [effectively]. If he uses drug s to get back, he'll be hooked - and he'll start hoovering up all the drugs in your bank, just to stay alive one more day - drugs that might be far better used elsewhere. Just food for thought...

Comment: @CJM Your answer would be better served by putting that comment you just made into the answer.

Comment: @CyberSkull - fair point (duly actioned) but that comment I *just made* was made nearly 2 years ago! ;)

Comment: @CJM I was reviewing your post as part of the new review system. I didn't feel that it merited a deletion recommendation, so I thought I'd just make a suggestion then.